# I'm having trouble adding to this code

Tags: arrays, vba

```
If vOverfly(arrayIndex, 10) <= 0 And vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7) = "CCYN" And Trim(vOverfly(arrayIndex, 3)) <> "--" Then
        resultCounter = resultCounter + 1
```

What do I need to do to add additional data to this line of code.  Currently this line copies data where a number is <= 0 and is identified by CCYN. I am needing to know if other parameters fall below 0 such as "EOTN", "EOTH" and "CCYV".  When I try to add these parameters it just ends up copying everything regardless of the number.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> And vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7) = "CCYN"
> ```

Try replacing the above part of code with this:

```
And IsNumeric (Application.match(vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7), _
  Array("CCYN", "EOTN", "EOTH", "CCYV"), 0))
```

If this code is inside a loop, you can make it faster by defining the array of values to match only once:

```
Dim arValues
arValues = Array("CCYN", "EOTN", "EOTH", "CCYV")

...

If vOverfly(arrayIndex, 10) <= 0 And _
  IsNumeric (Application.match(vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7), arValues, 0)) _ 
  And Trim(vOverfly(arrayIndex, 3)) <> "--" Then
    resultCounter = resultCounter + 1
```

Comment: nice, I like the IsNumeric screening out #N/A

Comment: @SMeaden Thanks. Your answer is good as well but I usually prefer this way because it is easier to read and "extend" :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use brackets around your OR test for CCYN, EOTN,EOTH etc.

```
Sub Test()
    If vOverfly(arrayIndex, 10) <= 0 And (vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7) = "CCYN" Or vOverfly(arrayIndex, 7) = "EOTN") And Trim(vOverfly(arrayIndex, 3)) <> "--" Then
        resultCounter = resultCounter + 1


End Sub
```